# Android custom rating bar issue

Tags: android, xml, ratingbar

i am trying to create a rating bar with custom image for stars.
I got some code from a website and works perfectly with the images provided by the author. But once i replace his images with mine(they have exactly the same format and dimensions) it doesn't work the same....

here is the **rating_bar.xml**

```
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_empty"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_empty"/>
<item
    android:id="@+android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rating_full"/>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="StarRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
</style>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar4"
    style="@style/StarRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Article pics

[image: Article's pics result]

My pics

[image]

Does anyone have an explanation? And yes i really searched a lot on that subject and the "popular" SO answers on similar question are not fitting to my issue

Answer (score 0):

can u please try this i have solved this using below changes

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar4"
    style="@style/StarRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

just change ur ratingbar height to wrap_content

Please inform me if not works for u we will find other way...